# WinError 10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: python, sockets

Im trying to create a simple chat server and I'm making it all GUI based. Im opening a window to enter your display name before it connects to the server, but for whatever reason it does this on the server end:

```
client.send('Connected to the chat'.encode('utf-8'))
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software 
in your host machine
```

I don't know why that is though. when I disable this code and just make it in the console it works just fine.

```
top = Toplevel() 

def GetNick(): 
    nickname = a.get()  
    top.destroy() 
    pass 

nick = Label(top, text='Pls Enter Your Display Name')
nick.pack() 

SubmitNick = Button(top, text='Submit', command=GetNick, borderwidth='0') 
SubmitNick.pack(side=BOTTOM) 

a = Entry(top, width = 10, borderwidth = '0', bg = 'dark gray', fg = 'white') 
a.pack(side=BOTTOM)
```

I tried using debugging, that didn't help to find the solution. Ive also tried to disable windows firewall but still no luck. I read it could be because its sending multiple messages at once but I don't see why that would be happening.

**Code For Server**

```
import threading
import socket

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 20200

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((host, port))
server.listen() 

clients = []
nicknames = []

def brodcast(message):
    for client in clients:
        client.send(message) 

def handle(client):
    while True:
        try:
            message = client.recv(1024)
            brodcast(message)
        except:
            index = clients.index(client)
            clients.remove(client)
            client.close()
            nickname = nicknames[index]
            brodcast(f'''
            {nickname} left the chat'''.encode('utf-8')) 
            nicknames.remove(nickname)
            break 

def recive():
    while True:
        client, address = server.accept()
        print(f"Connected with {str(address)}")
        client.send('NICK'.encode('utf-8'))
        nickname = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        nicknames.append(nickname)
        clients.append(client)
        print(f'{nickname} joined the chat!')
        brodcast(f'{nickname} joined the chat!'.encode('utf-8'))
        client.send('Connected to the chat'.encode('utf-8'))

        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle, args=(client,))
        thread.start()

recive()
```

**Code For Client**

```
import socket
import threading
from tkinter import* 
import tkinter as tk 
import tkinter.font as font 

root = Tk()
root.state("zoomed")
root.title('innit')

root.configure(bg='gray')

myFont = font.Font(family='Arial')

e = Entry(root, width = 100, borderwidth = '0', bg = 'dark gray', fg = 'black') 
e.pack(side=BOTTOM)

text = Text(root, width = 500, height = 53, borderwidth = '0', bg = 'dark gray', fg = 'black')
text.config(state='disabled') 
text.pack() 

top = Toplevel() 

def GetNick(): 
    nickname = a.get()  
    top.destroy() 
    pass 

nick = Label(top, text='Pls Enter Your Display Name')
nick.pack() 

SubmitNick = Button(top, text='Submit', command=GetNick, borderwidth='0') 
SubmitNick.pack(side=BOTTOM) 

a = Entry(top, width = 10, borderwidth = '0', bg = 'dark gray', fg = 'white') 
a.pack(side=BOTTOM)

#nickname = input("Enter your display name: ")

try: 
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.connect(('127.0.0.1', 20200))
except:
    print("Failed to connect to server!")

def recive():
    while True:
        try:
            message = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            if message == 'NICK':
                client.send(nickname.encode('utf-8'))
            else:
                text.config(state='normal') 
                text.insert(tk.INSERT, message) 
                text['font'] = myFont
                text.config(state='disabled')
        except:
            text.config(state='normal') 
            text.insert(tk.INSERT, 'An Error Accured ') 
            text['font'] = myFont
            text.config(state='disabled')
            client.close()
            break

def write(): 
        try:
            message = f'''
            [{nickname}]
            {e.get()}'''
            client.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
        except:
            print("Failed to send message!")

SendButton = Button(root, text = 'Send', borderwidth = '0', command = write)
SendButton.pack(side = BOTTOM ) 

NewLabel = Label(root, text = 'Warning: Do Not Send Any Personal Information Through The Chat!')
NewLabel.pack()

recive_thread = threading.Thread(target=recive)
recive_thread.start()

write_thread = threading.Thread(target=write)
write_thread.start() 

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This error has nothing to do with `tkinter`, but have you tried disabling your firewall? Also please remove the `tkinter` tag from the question

Comment: yes i have tried disabling my firewall.

Comment: Perhaps unrelated but `message = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')` is problematic. The receive may have gotten a partial utf-8 sequence causing the decode to fail.

Comment: ah. I just changed it to ascii and the same error accured. @tdelaney

Comment: @Superior125 Just noticed. You aren't supposed to call `tkinter` functions from different threads. That can cause trouble. That might not be the problem. Try adding a print before the `client.close()` on the client side. Does it trigger? If the client closes the connection but the server tries to write to it, it might cause that error.

Comment: it just says none when it closes. @TheLizzard